# IntelliJ Divides JUnit 4 Output Incorrectly

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I have a test class written using JUnit 4 that has multiple test methods. Each of the tests prints some important informational output. When I look in IntelliJ's log, however, some of the last output from the previous test is recorded as being part of the first.

Why this this? Is there a way of correcting this behaviour?

I'm just writing to `System.out`, and calling `flush` before returning from each test actually made the problem worse.

Comment: Did you click on each individual test run to ensure that this was the case, or are you looking at the aggregate overall run result?

Comment: Yes, if I look through any given test output (except the first, of course), I can clearly see output from a previous test at the top.

Comment: And you're certain that you're not putting some output like that in an `@After` or as part of your next test?

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of your test class that exhibits this behavior?  Those are the only two things I could think of off the top of my head without actually looking at code.

Comment: Hmm.. I can't actually share the specific code online, but I'll try to come up with a mock that exhibits the same behavior.

Comment: I found that adding a `Thread.sleep(10)` at the end of my `@Test` methods fixed it -- this isn't exactly a good solution, though. Might this have something to do with multithreading?

Comment: Not sure.  I'd need to see the actual test class.  I can't infer much more than what I've done above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply a bug. I workaround it by Thread#sleep in @After

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-66683

Test case:

```
public class LogBug {
    @Test
    public void see() {
        System.out.println("foo");
        throw new AssertionError("bar");
    }
    @Test
    public void see2() {
        System.out.println("foo2");
        throw new AssertionError("bar2");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I feared. Thanks for confirming.